# Automatically select item in RadioButtonList after clicking TextBox

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

So I currently have a page with two radio buttons from a RadioButtonList followed by two TextBoxes:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radioButtonList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Option1">Option1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Option2">Option2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Is there an easy way how I can make the first list item of the RadioButtonList selected after clicking on the first TextBox? This would be more user friendly since it is common to forget to check a value before continuing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of research I found the answer myself.
In the code behind inside the Page_Load function I put this line of code:

```
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "document.getElementById('" + radioButtonList1.ClientID + "_0').checked=true;");
```

I am pretty sure there is a better way but for now this seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery.

Your HTML looks something like this:

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radioButtonList1" value="Option1">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioButtonList1_0">Option1</label>
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$radioButtonList1" value="Option2">
<label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioButtonList1_1">Option2</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1">
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox2">
```

jQuery:

```
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBox1').focus(function() {
    $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioButtonList1_0').prop("checked", true);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1dqzwtnh/

---

Or just add `Selected="True"` to your first option in your aspx.